# How to translate some technical words from English that do not have a good translation?

Tags: traduction, terminologie

I am writing my thesis in French but I am not allowed to write any word in English. The problem is that some technical words are not usually into French, how can I translate them?

For example, these words are very hard for me to translate:

- backhaul
- plug-and-play
- ...

Also words that belong to someone cannot be translated like the name of an algorithm "quicksort" or the name of a model, ...

I would like to hear your suggestions.

Comment: Can you please ask one question at a time. I can see 3 questions in what you wrote.

Comment: Backhaul = "Télécommunication" ou "Réseau d'accès". Plug-And-Play doesn't have a translation (it's a marketed name, it's the same as many English products that don't have a translation, we just don't translate it). IE: Quicksort(English) = Quicksort(French)

Comment: I am curious to know where you are doing your thesis...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The translation of many technical words can be found on Wikipedia that going to the English articles then switching to French, e.g.:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort -> http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tri_rapide
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backhaul_(telecommunications) -> http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9seau_d%27acc%C3%A8s

Then http://www.linguee.fr/ if another great resource, e.g.:

- http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=plug-and-play -> prêt-à-l'emploi (this translation depends on the context).